# Dependencies Rule in Onion Architecture is confusing

Tags: dependency-injection, architecture, onion-architecture

In the Onion Architecture, the dependencies rule is outside-in, the arrow means outer layer depends on under layer as following image:

[image]

In real world, just assume we have projects are structured like this:

1. Project.DomainEntities
2. Project.RepositoryInterfaces (reference to {1})
3. Project.ServiceInterfaces (reference to {1} and {2})
4. Project.Test (reference to {1}, {2}, {3})
5. Project.Web (reference to {1}, {2}, {3})

The question is what is the arrow means or I set up the solution is incorrectly? If yes, could you help to point me out?

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get that diagram from? That's not a diagram that can be found in Jeffrey Palermo's [initial blog posts](https://jeffreypalermo.com/2008/07/the-onion-architecture-part-1/) and I find it rather misleading as Jeffrey states that "Inner layers define interfaces.  Outer layers implement interfaces," which is not something that your diagram visualizes.

Comment: Seconding @Steven's comment - The domain entities depend on the repository interfaces. Those interfaces aren't separate from the domain. They're part of the domain.

Answer (score 2):

[image]Arrows in this case would be reference directions; in C#, for instance, everything would reference the Domain Entities, but Domain Entities wouldn't hold references to anything.

The benefit here is that you're not mixing any infrastructure logic with your domain logic, it actually makes it impossible since your domain doesn't even know about the existence of things like your ORM, or even what a database is.

Going a step further, your service layer know what objects exist in your domain, so may set up an interface to persist your domain objects, but would be unable to have an object from your ORM returned to it; the concrete implementation would be the only one with knowledge of how to persist the domain objects and would have to convert it back from whatever form it was in to a domain object before returning it.